# Create a table from unrelated sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working in MySQL 5.7 (so don't have row_number and CTE).

I have the following structure:

```
-- create table
create table table1 (
  Id int not null auto_increment,
  JobId varchar(255) not null,
  FieldOrder int(11) not null,
  FieldName varchar(255) not null,
  FieldValue varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (Id)
); 

-- insert data
insert into table1 (JobId, FieldOrder, FieldName, FieldValue) values
('1', 1, 'Customer Id', 'C01'),
('1', 2, 'Order Number', '3923'),
('1', 3, 'Architect Id', 'DK'),
('2', 1, 'Customer Id', 'C02'),
('2', 2, 'Order Number', '23'),
('2', 3, 'Architect Id', 'AJ'),
('3', 1, 'Customer Id', 'C03'),
('3', 2, 'Plot Id', '3'),
('3', 3, 'Architect Id', ''),
('4', 1, 'Customer Id', 'C01');
```

For each field name and value, I want to list all values removing duplicates, without joining on job id so that I don't get nulls in places.

I have written a query that gets me what I want:

```
SET @row_number_one = 0;
SET @row_number_two = 0;
SET @row_number_three = 0;
SET @row_number_four = 0;
select coalesce(t1.FieldValue, '') as "customer_id", 
coalesce(t4.FieldValue, '') as "plot_id",
coalesce(t2.FieldValue, '') as "order_number",
coalesce(t3.FieldValue, '') as "architect_id" from (
select FieldValue, (@row_number_one:=@row_number_one + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Customer Id') as t1
left join (select FieldValue, (@row_number_two:=@row_number_two + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Order Number') as t2 on t1.rnk = t2.rnk
left join (select FieldValue, (@row_number_three:=@row_number_three + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Architect Id') as t3 on t1.rnk = t3.rnk
left join (select FieldValue, (@row_number_four:=@row_number_four + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Plot Id') as t4 on t1.rnk = t4.rnk;
```

I'm not sure if there are better ways of getting that data given the constraints of the MySQL version.

The query above gives me the following output:

```
| customer_id | plot_id | order_number | architect_id |
| ----------- | ------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| C01         | 3       | 3923         | DK           |
| C02         |         | 23           | AJ           |
| C03         |         |              |              |
| C01         |         |              |              |
```

I want to change my query so that I don't get duplicates in any of the columns, I thought this would be a matter of adding a `distinct`, so I tried it on the `customer_id` column first. I updated my query to:

```
SET @row_number_one = 0;
SET @row_number_two = 0;
SET @row_number_three = 0;
SET @row_number_four = 0;
select distinct(coalesce(t1.FieldValue, '')) as "customer_id", 
coalesce(t4.FieldValue, '') as "plot_id",
coalesce(t2.FieldValue, '') as "order_number",
coalesce(t3.FieldValue, '') as "architect_id" from (
select FieldValue, (@row_number_one:=@row_number_one + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Customer Id') as t1
left join (select FieldValue, (@row_number_two:=@row_number_two + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Order Number') as t2 on t1.rnk = t2.rnk
left join (select FieldValue, (@row_number_three:=@row_number_three + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Architect Id') as t3 on t1.rnk = t3.rnk
left join (select FieldValue, (@row_number_four:=@row_number_four + 1) AS rnk
from table1
where FieldName = 'Plot Id') as t4 on t1.rnk = t4.rnk;
```

That doesn't seem to do anything on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rw7LMXMSyBssVtW2fcPYns/1) (update it and add distinct), but on my local install, I basically get:

```
+-------------+--------+--------------+---------------+
| customer_id | plot_id | order_number | architect_id |
+-------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
| DKN         |         |              |              |
| BNC         |         |              |              |
| ABC         |         |              |              |
+-------------+--------+--------------+---------------+
```

So I basically lose the other data that I had. How do I update my query to get:

```
| customer_id | plot_id | order_number | architect_id |
| ----------- | ------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| C01         | 3       | 3923         | DK           |
| C02         |         | 23           | AJ           |
| C03         |         |              |              |
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write...

Comment: I did! Right at the bottom.

Comment: *I want to change my query so that I don't get duplicates in any of the columns* Imagine that a row `('4', 2, 'Order Number', '3924')` is added to the rowset (and customer_id='C01' have 2 different order numbers now) - what output do you need in this case?

Comment: Good question @Akina, the output would be this: https://i.imgur.com/VfDA33M.png

Comment: *the output would be this* ??? why the order 3924 is moved from customer C01 to C03?

Comment: As I said, in terms of rows, the data is *totally unrelated*. I know it is weird :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're bound to get NULLs if you insist on returning all these distinct lists in a single result set, unless each column has exactly the same number of distinct values.

The problem is that you're treating a relational query result set as if it's a spreadsheet. It's not. The columns in a given row *are* related. That's why it's a relational database.

If you just want to get the distinct values for each attribute, it's much simpler and more correct from a relational standpoint to do separate queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FieldValue AS customer_id 
FROM table1 WHERE FieldName = 'Customer Id';

SELECT DISTINCT FieldValue AS plot_id 
FROM table1 WHERE FieldName = 'Plot Id';

SELECT DISTINCT FieldValue AS order_number 
FROM table1 WHERE FieldName = 'Order Number';

SELECT DISTINCT FieldValue AS architect_id 
FROM table1 WHERE FieldName = 'Architect Id';
```

No need for complex subqueries or user-defined variables or window functions. Just plain SQL that is easy to write and easy to read and easy to modify. Not every problem needs to be solved in a single SQL query.

This doesn't arrange the results as columns of a single result set, but *that's wrong anyway.* They're not related, so they shouldn't be in a single result set.